# Windows Forms, Set method throws string.isnullorempty exception? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

This a class which holds the value of first and last name.
Another class called attendee inherates from person.

```
class Person
{
    static private string FirstName;
    static private string LastName;

    static public string firstname          
    {                                      
        get
        {
            return FirstName;
        }
        set
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("First name must not be blank!");
            }
            FirstName = value;
        }
    }
```

This is in my GUI class and the method retrieves the value of the first name and updates it within the Person class.

```
private void BtnSet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)          
    {                                                               
        Attendee.firstname = FirstName.Text;
... //more code (not relevant)
    }
```

For some reason this throws the exception from the Person class but I do not understand why?

Comment: You have FirstName declared as a static member, thus your reference to FirstName.Text looks to the Static FirstName and gets its Text property which doesn't exist, hence the exception. Is a static class required? or did you do that to make code "work"? In that code that exceptions, do you want the Text property of a Textbox? It's name probably isn't FirstName ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You check the `FirstName` field which is initially null in the *setter* of `firstName` property, use instead

```
 set
 {
     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
     {
         throw new ArgumentException("First name must not be blank!");
     }
     FirstName = value;
 }
```

Comment: Working fine so far! Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't Value be lowercase?